# Scratch off reveal with HTML5 canvas -- Add fade out element

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I've followed this tutorial to create a "draw to reveal" effect on my website: http://thenewcode.com/1120/Scratch-Off-Reveal-with-HTML5-Canvas. I'd like the 'front' image to be this [video asset](https://player.vimeo.com/video/697100253?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1), and I'd also like the "revealed" path (or each dot drawn) to fade out after a set time after it is drawn (like a fading trail behind the mouse), but could not figure out how to do it. I've tried re-drawing the img after each `drawDot()` call, but that seems to just draw the entire "revealed" image. Thanks!

Edit: added request for video to be 'front'

Comment: What do you mean by **I'd like the "revealed" path (or each dot drawn) to fade out after a set time after it is drawn**? Does it mean that for example after 5 seconds the first image comes back to screen like that the user does not draw that path over first image?

Comment: Essentially I want a fading trail behind the mouse that reveals the image below. In the example above, the trail is permanent. I would like the trail to fade back into the original image.

Comment: This is what I got up to so far: https://codepen.io/zachjensz/pen/vYpdbrN My draw image function doesn't seem to work, going to sleep on it.

Comment: What have you tried? and where did you get stuck?? ... this question keeps changing to suit your needs, you should ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, here is my solution:

Every time a dot is drawn, set a clearDot:

```js
setClearDot(brushPos.x, brushPos.y, CLEARDOT_DELAY_MILLISECONDS)
```

Which will be drawn after a set delay:

```js
function setClearDot(x, y, delay) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    drawClearDot(x, y)
  }, delay);
}
```

Draw a cleardot:

```js
function drawClearDot(x, y) {
  const squareX = x - brushRadius
  const squareY = y - brushRadius
  const squareSize = brushRadius * 2
  bridgeCanvas.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  bridgeCanvas.drawImage(img, squareX, squareY, squareSize, squareSize, squareX, squareY, squareSize, squareSize);
}
```

Hopefully a square works well enough, first two vars get the co-ords of the dot and turn them into top left corner of the square. [Composite operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) has to be changed back to normal (This took me many hours to figure out... it was painful trust me). Then we [draw part of the coloured image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) back.

Here's a working snippet with my solution:

```js
CLEARDOT_DELAY_MILLISECONDS = 1500;

var bridge = document.getElementById("bridge"),
  bridgeCanvas = bridge.getContext('2d'),
  brushRadius = (bridge.width / 100) * 5,
  img = new Image();

if (brushRadius < 50) {
  brushRadius = 50
}

img.onload = function() {
  bridgeCanvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0, bridge.width, bridge.height);
}
img.loc = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/';
img.filename = 'calgary-bridge-2013.jpg';
if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
  var nameParts = img.filename.split('.');
  img.src = img.loc + nameParts[0] + "-2x" + "." + nameParts[1];
} else {
  img.src = img.loc + img.filename;
}

function detectLeftButton(event) {
  if ('buttons' in event) {
    return event.buttons === 1;
  } else if ('which' in event) {
    return event.which === 1;
  } else {
    return event.button === 1;
  }
}

function getBrushPos(xRef, yRef) {
  var bridgeRect = bridge.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: Math.floor((xRef - bridgeRect.left) / (bridgeRect.right - bridgeRect.left) * bridge.width),
    y: Math.floor((yRef - bridgeRect.top) / (bridgeRect.bottom - bridgeRect.top) * bridge.height)
  };
}

function drawDot(mouseX, mouseY) {
  bridgeCanvas.beginPath();
  bridgeCanvas.arc(mouseX, mouseY, brushRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  bridgeCanvas.fillStyle = '#000';
  bridgeCanvas.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  bridgeCanvas.fill();
}

function drawClearDot(x, y) {
  const squareX = x - brushRadius
  const squareY = y - brushRadius
  const squareSize = brushRadius * 2
  bridgeCanvas.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  bridgeCanvas.drawImage(img, squareX, squareY, squareSize, squareSize, squareX, squareY, squareSize, squareSize);
}

bridge.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var brushPos = getBrushPos(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  var leftBut = detectLeftButton(e);
  if (leftBut) {
    drawDot(brushPos.x, brushPos.y);
    setClearDot(brushPos.x, brushPos.y, CLEARDOT_DELAY_MILLISECONDS)
  }
}, false);

bridge.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var touch = e.targetTouches[0];
  if (touch) {
    var brushPos = getBrushPos(touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
    drawDot(brushPos.x, brushPos.y);
    setClearDot(brushPos.x, brushPos.y, CLEARDOT_DELAY_MILLISECONDS)
  }
}, false);

function setClearDot(x, y, delay) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    drawClearDot(x, y)
  }, delay);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#bridge {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943.jpg');
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943.jpg') 1x, url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943-2x.jpg') 2x);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  height: auto;
  cursor: crosshair;
  cursor: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/circular-cursor.png) 53 53, crosshair;
}

#bridgeContainer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Avenir, sans-serif;
}

#bridgeContainer figcaption {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<figure id="bridgeContainer">
  <canvas id="bridge" width="750" height="465"></canvas>
  <figcaption>Downtown Calgary in 2013 and 1943; mouse down or touch on photo to reveal</figcaption>
</figure>
```

That took longer than I'm willing to admit

Comment: Works great! My next step is to figure out how to do this with a video as the 'front' image, so if you're up for the challenge that would be awesome. Will accept the answer though well done!

Comment: @ScottMyers Yeah if you add the video to your question somehow I'll definitely give it a shot

Comment: Edited to add video asset!

Comment: @zach-jensz this is a fantastic answer. You may need to check it on a retina display tho (no one ever tests canvas on retina displays! and it always messes up. the image comes back twice the size on my mac) you can get the pixel ratio with `window.devicePixelRatio`. this will be either 1 on normal displays or 2 on retina. So you can multiple positions by the pixel ratio without affecting normal devices but making sure you get the correct pixels on retina displays.

Answer (score 2):

### Render a video

To render a video create a [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) set the `src` and listen for the `canPlay` event.

Use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to update the video. You can draw the [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) on a canvas directly using [ctx.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

### Scratch FX

To create the Scratch FX create a second canvas (call overlay in example) the same size as the background image. Fill that image with no transparent pixels.

Use the mouse (or touch) coords to draw lines on the overlay image (canvas) with [ctx.globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) set to `"destination-out"`. This will remove pixels where you draw.

Then set [ctx.globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) to `"source-atop"` and draw the video element onto the overlay. This will only set non transparent pixels with the current video frame.

Then draw the background image to the canvas, and then the overlay.

All done. See demo for the nuts and bolts.

### Demo

The following snippet does the above.

```js
// Source wiki commons. Attribution in the leading credits.
const mediaSource = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv";

var showHelp = true; 
var bgReady = false;

// create and load background image
const bgImg = new Image;
bgImg.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=256&g=1";
bgImg.addEventListener("load", () => bgReady = true, {once: true});
const W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Show state and setup help settings
ctx.font = "32px arial";
ctx.fillText("Loading...", 30, 60);
ctx.font = "24px arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = 4;  

// setup overlay canvas
const overlay = copyImg(canvas);
const ctxO = overlay.getContext("2d");
ctxO.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
ctxO.lineJoin = "round";
ctxO.lineCap = "round";
function copyImg(img) {
  const can = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {width: img.width, height: img.height});
  return can;
}

// create video element and load media. Will call StartVideo when ready   
const video = createVideo(mediaSource, StartVideo);
function createVideo(mediaSource, animCallback) {
  const video = document.createElement("video"); 
  video.src = mediaSource;
  video.autoPlay = false;
  video.loop = true;
  video.muted = true;
  video.addEventListener("canplay", animCallback, {once: true});
  video.addEventListener("error", error, {once: true})  
  function error(e) { console.log("Could not load video!!! ", e); }  
  return video
}
function StartVideo() {
  video.play();
  renderLoop();
}

// Create simple mouse listeners
const mouse = createMouse();
function createMouse() {
  const m = {x : 0, y : 0, px: 0, py: 0, button : false, element: canvas, bound: null};  
  m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
  function mouseEvents(e) {
    m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
    m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
  }
  ["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
  return m;
}

// main render loop
function renderLoop() {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0, W, H);
        if (mouse.button) {
            ctxO.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
            ctxO.strokeStyle = "#0008";
            ctxO.beginPath();
            ctxO.lineTo(mouse.px, mouse.py);
            ctxO.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            ctxO.lineWidth = 30;
            ctxO.stroke();
            ctxO.lineWidth = 26;
            ctxO.stroke();
            ctxO.lineWidth = 22;
            ctxO.stroke();
            showHelp = false;   
        }
        ctxO.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
        ctxO.drawImage(video, 0, 0, W, H);
        ctx.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, W, H);
        if (showHelp) {              
            ctx.strokeText( "Click drag to reveal", 32, 62);
            ctx.fillText( "Click drag to reveal", 30, 60);
        }
    }
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is almost there! Just missing the fade out of the revealed line after a given interval. (Fading trail behind the mouse as its dragged, instead of the trail never going away)

Comment: @ScottMyers you can use `ctx.globalAlpha`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha just before drawing the overlay to the main canvas `ctx.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, W, H);` to fade out the video